# Why does Eclipse ant editor warn me

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am having some trouble (annoyance really) with ANT editor in Eclipse where it is displaying me a warning *"Reference build.classpath not found."* on the following block:

```
<target name="generate" depends="..., mvn-depends">
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
        <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
    </taskdef>
    ...
</target>
```

With `mvn-depends` target looking like this:

```
<target name="mvn-depends">
    <artifact:dependencies pathId="build.classpath">
        <pom refid="my.pom" />
    </artifact:dependencies>
</target>
```

The rest of the references to `build.classpath` in the build file are not throwing any warnings and the and build runs just fine without any errors, so it does not seem to be amounting to much.

Still, ignoring a warning makes me feel sort of dirty every time I have to edit that file. Specifically, not knowing if this is a bug in Eclipse ant build file validation code or a potential problem in the way the build file has been structured, that Eclipse has identified.

If anyone has any ideas on why this warning is being shown and whether it is safe to ignore or maybe even disable from preferences and would care to share that knowledge, I would definitely be grateful for the knowledge.

**Edit:**

As requested, here is an example of a reference to `build.classpath` that does not cause any warnings:

```
<javac deprecation="off" debug="on" source="1.7" target="1.7" encoding="UTF-8"
       includeantruntime="false" memoryMaximumSize="512M" fork="true">
    <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
</javac>
```

Comment: So could you also post a reference to `build.classpath` that doesn't cause an Eclipse warning?

Comment: I added the snippet of code to the question where `build.classpath` does **not** cause a warning.

Comment: Is the target that the `<javac>` is in has `depends="..., mvn-depends"`?

Comment: Yes and no. The `javac` is wrapped in the `<presetdef >`, but the resulting task is used by targets that have dependency on `mvn-depends` target.

Comment: As the editor could recognize refids and other elements that Ant specifies, I guess that the editor does something similar to Ant's build file parsing process. That is, references in `<taskdef>` may be checked, while `<javac>` is not -- And, the `build.classpath` is set during runtime. So eclipse can't find it. Just a guess -- if there is another `taskdef` that is not warned, then I am wrong.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense - could you make this into an answer?

Comment: Provided some ways to prove my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the editor could recognize refids and other elements that Ant specifies, I guess that the editor does something similar to Ant's build file parsing process.

That is, parse this ant build file into a `Project` object, and references in `<taskdef>` may be checked, while `<javac>` may not.

Since the build.classpath is set during runtime and it is set by something other than things like `<classpath>`, Eclipse may not find it.

I don't have strong prove about this. But something can be done to make us know more.

- First, copy the `<javac>` to the same target where the warned
  `<taskdef>` exists, to see if the `<javac>` gets a warning;
- Then, copy the `<taskdef>` to the same target where the presetdefed
  `<javac>` exists, to see if the `<taskdef>` still gets a warning;
- Third, in target "generate", comment out the `<taskdef>` part, and
  check if the `<xjc ... />` call gets a warning.

For the first one, I expect "NO", while for the other two, I expect "YES". Otherwise, my guess is wrong.

And it makes sense that it is just a warning -- things Eclipse can't find in editing time could exist during runtime.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case. Turning "Incomplete classpath" checking in the Eclipse Ant preferences buildfile problems tab (`Prederences` -> `Ant` -> `Editor`) to "Ignore" removed the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given the path element location correctly as bellow.

```
<property name="dependencyfinder.home" value="C:/DependencyFinder"/>

<path id="dependencyfinder">
    <pathelement location="${dependencyfinder.home}/lib/aaa.jar"/> 
</path>


<taskdef classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
    <classpath refid="dependencyfinder"/>
</taskdef>
```

Note: DependencyFinder has a folder lib and lib has aaa.jar

Please check the bellow link for more information
[Click here](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/tasks/definitions.html)

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not make sense and it doesn't answer my question. Obviously, the classpath contains what I need for defining xjc task, as the ant file runs without as much as a hickup. The question I am asking is why is this warning shown and what does it signify?

Comment: Check whether com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask is available in the lib file which u mentiond in the class path.